# Add-Migration Error in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am following Julie Lerman's Getting Started with Entity Framework Core 2.0 tutorial. I have installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version 2.0.2. When I try to run add-migration initial (Package Manager Console) in VS 2017 I am obtaining the below error :

`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'`

When I run `dotnet --version i get 2.1.3.` Can anybody help me rectify this error.

Screenshot :

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in Package Manager Console,  have you selected the project, from the Default project dropdown,  which has the db context/entity framework references

Comment: Yes it is set to Data Project. Yes it has the EF Core References and the DbContext. I have installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design in an Empty ASP.NET Core Project and have designated it as the StartUp Project too.

Comment: maybe try re-install the entity framework ?https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: I Re-installed. still the same error :(

Comment: Is your startup project set to the correct project? See [Using the EF Core PMC Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#using-the-tools)

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question with a screenshot. I have selected the UI Project which contains a reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design as my StartUp project.

Comment: @bricelam is correct this was probably caused because your startup roject was .UI and not the Data project

Comment: Hi @bricelam. Thanks. After changing my Startup Project to Data It did work. I selected UI as Startup Project as it was done the same way by the author too. Thanks Again :)

Comment: Not having Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design installed caused the error for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the very same Pluralsight video, I ran into this same problem. After running:

```
PM> install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

with the *default project* set to `SomeUI`

I was able to get the `add-migration initial` to run without any problems at all, after doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I know the following is not an exact answer to my own question. But rather than waiting to somebody answer how to solve it in VS 2017 ( Windows ) I am taking a Terminal Approach on my Mac and using dotnet cli to recreate the solution (Julie Lerman hope you won't send your favorite Samurai for a battle :P)

**Note: Steps below is for Mac. Windows users having SQl Server Installed can Skip Step 1.**

**Step 1 : Install Docker and Pull MSSQL Image**

a. Install docker and pull latest mssql image for linux using :

```
sudo docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

b. Start the docker image using :

```
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD= 
    <ComplexPassword>' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

c. Optional. Install sql-cli using `npm install -g sql-cli`. Now you can connect to Sql Server running on Docker using `mssql -s 127.0.0.1 -u sa -p.`

**Step 2 : Create .sln, .csproj and add references using dotnet cli**

1. Create directory for Project and under it create a .sln file using: `dotnet new sln -n SamuraiApp`
2. Create Data and Domain class Library Projects using : `dotnet new classlib -n SamuraiApp.Data` and `dotnet new classlib -n SamuraiApp.Domain`
3. Create and Empty ASP.NET Core Project using `dotnet new web -n SamuraiApp.UI`
4. Add Entity Frmaework Core to Data ClassLibrary using : `cd SamuraiApp.Data` and `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
5. Add Entity Framework Core Design to UI Project Using : `cd SamuraiApp.UI/` and `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`
6. Run `dotnet restore`

**Step 3: Add References**

1. Execute `dotnet add SamuraiApp.Data reference SamuraiApp.Domain/SamuraiApp.Domain.csproj` to add Domain as a reference to Data.
2. Execute `dotnet add SamuraiApp.UI reference SamuraiApp.Domain/SamuraiApp.Domain.csproj` to add Domain as reference to UI.
3. Execute `dotnet add SamuraiApp.UI reference SamuraiApp.Data/SamuraiApp.Data.csproj` to add Data as reference to UI.
4. Execute below commands to add all three projects to solution:

   dotnet sln add SamuraiApp.Data/SamuraiApp.Data.csproj
       dotnet sln add SamuraiApp.Domain/SamuraiApp.Domain.csproj
       dotnet sln add SamuraiApp.UI/SamuraiApp.UI.csproj
5. Open SamuraiApp.Data.csproj in your favorite text editor and add the following:

```js
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference 
      Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

To enable dotnet ef.

**Step 4 : Write Domain Classes, DataContext class and add migration**
cd into SamuraiApp.Data folder and execute the below command to add initial migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project ../SamuraiApp.UI
```

Hope it helps to somebody. But still In windows using VS 2017 I am facing issues and would hope somebody will help me solve it.

Thanks :)