# Scaffolding Error Microsoft.EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, scaffolding, razor-pages, assembly-references

I am currently learning how to work with Razor Pages using the following tutorial on Microsoft's Website:

[Getting Started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

In the [Add a Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-2.1) section of the tutorial, it shows how to Scaffold using the Command Prompt. However, upon executing the command, I am met with the following Error:

```cs
Building project ...
Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
Running the generator 'razorpage'...
Attempting to compile the application in memory.
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext: 'Movie'
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)
RunTime 00:00:49.26
```

As far as I can tell, my code in VSC17 is as prescribed within the tutorial. I also just updated VSC17 right after creating the project file (But before attempting to Scaffold), if that may have any effect. Thanks in advance.

Append: I was able to successfully execute **Add-Migration** *Initial* prior to posting this question. It's when I have to enter the following command into the prompt that leads to issues:

> dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc MovieContext -udl -outDir Pages\Movies --referenceScriptLibraries

**SOLVED**

It was the update of VSC17 that messed up the dependencies. Created a new Project, and everything worked like a charm. Hashtag face in palm...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add-Migration Error in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510374/add-migration-error-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @devlincarnate I was able to execute Add-Migration without error. It's the following step that's creating the error.